# How can calculate file data or records in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, file-upload, fwrite

I am using to write some logs to write in locally when  logs or data count above 50 i want to post the data to server. Then i write the next 50 logs values. My question is how to get the file count and how can i maintain this any one help me.

Comment: Look at the [NSFileManager documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilemanager_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: @Lefteris I want the count records inside the File anyway thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT** count records inside the File

Notice when addnew log to file add with \n line character so we can know how many logs added

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:yourFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSArray *arrLogs = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
NSLog(@"Count of logs : %d",[arrLogs count]);
```

---

check this to how to get count of contents like this:

```
NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:dirPath error:nil];
```

Now filter contents like this:

```
NSPredicate *fltrtxt = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self ENDSWITH '.txt'"];
NSArray *onlytxts = [dirContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:fltrtxt];
```

Now count is:

```
if([onlytxts count] >= 50)
{
  //save new log to doc dir
  // post data to server;
  //after posting data u can do anything
}
```

Comment: for checking each file extension in NSPredicate